# How to insert record into two mysql table using php?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have to two tables in my database one is "test1" and the second is "test2".
and the field for test 1 is "id","survey_no","lastname" and for the field of test i have "id","survey_no","address" the id for test1 and test2 are primary key and set to auto-increment..what i want here is that what ever i insert in "survey_no" in test1 should also be insert inserted in "survey_no in test2"..can somebody please help me with it..please..

I have here the code for insertion called sample.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="POST" class="signin" action="" name="add" id="form1">
<fieldset class="textbox">
    <label class="province_id">
        <span>province id</span>
            <input id="province" name="survey_no" type="number" value="" autocomplete="on" placeholder="survey_no">
    </label>
    <label class="municipality">
        <span>Municipality</span>
            <input id="municipality" name="lastname" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="lastname">
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Save</button>
    <button id="submit" type="reset" name="reset">Reset</button> 
    </fieldset>


    <?php
    $conn=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
            if(!$conn)
            {
                die('could not connect:' .mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db("sample",$conn);

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {

            $survey_no=$_POST['survey_no'];
            $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];

            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test1`(survey_no,lastname) 
     VALUES ('$survey_no','$lastname')");

     if($result)
    {
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
    "alert('Saved!');".
    "</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
    "alert('Failed!');".
    "</script>";
        } 
}

?>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Warning : **mysql_query** is deprecated !

Comment: Error 2 : `id="submit"` cant be more than 1

Comment: Yes, you should have unique id

Comment: @jQuery i'm sorry for that, i forgot to change that one..maybe i just called it submit1...

Comment: i know that mysql is depracated but i will change to mysql but first i need to finish this first before i go to mysqli..can you help me with it?

Comment: @tiGer can you help me with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so far i understand you want this

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test1`(survey_no,lastname) 
     VALUES ('$survey_no','$lastname')");


$result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test2`(survey_no) 
     VALUES ('$survey_no')");
```

Comment: i have one last question, it is related to this..how can i insert the records from test1 to test 2?

Comment: you want to add all record of test1 in test 2?

Comment: something like that,is it possible even if test1 and test2 has different fields?

Comment: yes it is possible fetching from test1 and insert into test2

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * fron `test1`");  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$survey_no=$row['survey'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test2`(survey_no) 
     VALUES ('$survey_no')");
}   you will achieve like this..

Comment: what if i have in common fields in test1 and test2 something like both test1 and test has id,survey_no,lastname and in table test2 there's additional field like location,area,age.. and i want is that i i insert in test1 should also insert in test2, to be more specific i want it to insert to the same fields..

Comment: add the column and add the values it will insert all the values from test1 to test2.